# Succinctly specify exact state of git repository

Tags: git, github

I have a very basic question. Say I've cloned a public repository, e.g., one available on github. I now want to communicate with other developers, e.g., to file a bug. What's the best way to communicate the code version to other developers? Can I somehow interrogate my local copy of the repo and send them something like a SHA-1 hash that encapsulates the version? Must I include branch information, if that makes sense?

How do people typically do what I'm asking with git?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you haven't made your own changes and just want to reference an existing revision, you can run

```
git log
```

at the command line, and copy the SHA hash appearing after the word "commit" for the revision you're looking for.

On github, you can get the same information by clicking Commits, hovering over the desired revision, and clicking the little clipboard icon that appears.

If you have made changes and you're trying to communicate those, the best way is probably to commit to your own fork on github and issue a pull request to the repository managers.

Answer (score 2):

Any commit is unique so you can use that if you which.

There is also `git describe` that gives a great name from any commit but it requires at least one tag created. If you create tags out of every release this is a great way do describe any commit.

The name given by `git describe` is also a valid committish so you can use it as any other SHA.

Comment: Sorry, just to clarify: how would one typically get the SHA of a particular commit? I see two ways: (1) a shortened version is printed when one runs 'git commit', (2) 'git log'. I assume these are the typical ways of getting the SHA. Is that right? Thanks...

Comment: Another answer to this question suggests that, indeed, 'git log' is the typical way to obtain a SHA.

Comment: @WillNelson: yes, `git log` is quite typical.  You can also turn a "human readable name" (like a branch or tag name, or the output of `git describe` although sometimes that's not very readable :-) ") into a raw SHA-1 using `git rev-parse`.  Most of the time, "human readable" is superior to "raw SHA-1" for most humans, of course....